# Access Data In Next.js From PostgreSQL Database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, next.js

I have created a postgreSQL database on my local machine. I have one table in it called 'posts'. I fetch the data from the database using fetch(), and make it usable in Javascript using json():

```
Blog.getInitialProps = async function(props) {
    // API call to database
    console.log('getting props');
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:2000/blog-posts');
    const blogData = await res.json();

    console.log('blogData: ', blogData);

return {
    blogData: blogData
};
};
```

Now comes the problem when I try to use the data (blogData). The fetch() and or .json() returns a format like this:

```
// blogData
[
{
    slug_name: 'post-1',
    post_name: 'Post 1',
    post_content: 'Hello world. This is Post 1.',
    author_name: 'Jedakiah Moore',
    author_image: 'Jedakiah_image',
    post_date: '2019-01-24T06:00:00.000Z',
    amount_of_comments: 0 
},
{
    slug_name: 'post-2',
    post_name: 'Post 2',
    post_content: 'Hello world. This is Post 2.',
    author_name: 'Jedakiah Moore',
    author_image: 'Jedakiah_image',
    post_date: '2019-01-24T06:00:00.000Z',
    amount_of_comments: 0 
}
]
```

I try to render each of the objects in the blogData array as their own blog post preview using map(). This would allow me to use dot notation to access every key in each object (ex: author_name, post_date, et cetera):

```
const Blog = (props) => (
 <div className="blog-post-feed">
     <ul className="blog-post-list">
         {props.blogData.map(({post }) => (
             <li key={post.slug_name}>
                 <Link href={`/posts?id=${post.slug_name}`}>
                     <a className="blog-post-preview" title={ post.post_name }>
                         {post.post_name}
                     </a>
                 </Link>
             </li>
         ))}
     </ul>
 </div>
)
export default Blog
```

This gets an error because none of the objects in the blogData array contain a key called 'post'. The example array below, called blogData2, shows how map() expects my returned data (blogData) to look. I created blogData2 as a hard-coded array in order to test if map() would work with this format:

```
Blog.getInitialProps = async function(props) {
    const blogData2 = [
        { 
            post: {
                post_slug: 'post-1',
                post_name: 'Post 1' 
            },
        },
        {
            post: {
                post_slug: 'post-2',
                post_name: 'Post 2' 

            }  
        }
    ];

    return {
        blogData2: blogData2
    };
};

const Blog = (props) => (
     <div className="blog-post-feed">
         <ul className="blog-post-list">
             { props.blogData2.map(({ post }) => (
                 <li key={ post.slug_name }>
                     <Link href={ `/posts?id=${ post.slug_name }` }>
                         <a className="blog-post-preview" title={post.post_name }>
                             { post.post_name }
                         </a>
                     </Link>
                 </li>
                    )) }
         </ul>
     </div>
    )
    export default Blog
```

The map() method seems to work with blogData2, but now I need to know how to get my returned data from the database (blogData) to fit this structure (blogData2). Or is there a better way to display and access my returned data (blogData)?

Comment: Possible share more details about ` 'post' does not exist in the returned data`. Unable to get what you have explained.

Comment: @SelvaTS  I edited my question. Let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: change this line `{props.blogData.map(({post }) => (` to `{props.blogData.map(post => (`. You are destructing in the map function and it expects `post` as object. Actually you need a param not object.

Comment: @SelvaTS  Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, you have issue in calling the `map` function in the below line of code.

```
{props.blogData.map(({post }) => (
    <li key={post.slug_name}>
      <Link href={`/posts?id=${post.slug_name}`}>
          <a className="blog-post-preview" title={ post.post_name }>
             {post.post_name}
          </a>
       </Link>
     </li>
  ))}
```

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function expects current value (element) and index (optional). But in the above code you are [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `blogData` with a `post` object. There is no `post` object in `blogData`. But in the `blogData2` object, you deliberately created `post` object. So it is working. To fix this, just remove the destructing the object and it works.

```
{props.blogData.map(post => (
    <li key={post.slug_name}>
      <Link href={`/posts?id=${post.slug_name}`}>
          <a className="blog-post-preview" title={ post.post_name }>
             {post.post_name}
          </a>
       </Link>
     </li>
  ))}
```